# Android - Is possible to make a cell phone transmit FM waves?

Tags: android, motorola

I have a Motorola Razr D3. I was thinking about the possibility of use my cell phone like a FM Transmissor, so i can send a music in FM waves to my Radio in my car. Is it possible? Exist any app for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Only if your device has dedicated FM transmitter hardware or is a software-defined radio device. Statistically speaking, it is *very* unlikely that any device that you own meets one of those criteria.